# by default, does stderr start as a duplicate file descriptor of stdout?

Tags: linux, bash

Does stderr **start out** as a duplicate FD of stdout?

i.e. considering [dup(2)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html), is stderr initialized kind of like so?

```
int stderr = dup(stdout); // stdout = 1
```

---

In the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput), there's a code example

```
$ grep proud file 'not a file' > proud.log 2> proud.log
```

The author states

> We've created two FDs that both point to the same file, independently of each other. The results of this are not well-defined. Depending on how the operating system handles FDs, some information written via one FD may clobber information written through the other FD.

and further says

> We need to prevent having two independent FDs working on the same destination or source. We can do this by duplicating FDs

So basically, 2 independent FDs on the same file = broken

Well, I know that stdout & stderr both point to my terminal by default. Since they can both function properly (i.e. i don't see mish-mashed output+error messages), does that mean that they're not independent FDs? And thus, stderr is a duplicate FD of stdout? (or vice versa)

Comment: What is your specific question? Yes by default both stdout and stderr gets logged at terminal

Comment: generally speaking, is stderr a duplicate FD (of stdout) that can be "promoted" to an independent FD later on? (e.g. by redirection to a destination other than the terminal, like a file)

Comment: You would have to define what is a "duplicate FD". Such thing doesn't exists. When you duplicate a FD you have two descriptors. Separate two descriptors. In the sentence `Depending on how the operating system handles FDs,` concentrate on the word "depending".

Comment: Yes it's a duplicate fd pointing to the terminal device. However the terminal device is not a regular file, it's managed by the kernel.

Comment: @KamilCuk by "duplicate FD", I mean an FD returned from [dup(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dup_(system_call))

Answer (score 0):

No, stderr is *not* a duplicate of stdout.
They work in parallel, independent and asynchronously.
Which means that in a race condition, you might even 'mish-mash' as you say.
One practical difference is also that stderr output will be ignored when you pipe your output to a subsequent command: 
Practical example:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "written to stdout"
echo "written to stderr" 1>&2
exit 0

~$ ./tst.sh 
written to stdout
written to stderr
~$ ./tst.sh | xargs -n1 -I{} echo "this came through the pipe:{}"
written to stderr
this came through the pipe:written to stdout
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the example!

I understand this much, but my question was a bit different. It was poorly asked on my part, so I've updated my question to be more specific